# Использование Google maps вместо Bing WP7?

Tags: google-maps, windows-phone-7

Сломал всю голову. Как использовать карты google вместо bing карт. Как я понял котрол используется одинаковый - `Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps`. Но как заставить отображать google карты не могу понять... Вся проблема что bing не поддерживает русский, а использует латиницу...

Answer (score 1):

Доброго времени суток! По быстрому нашлось http://themightyhedgehog.blogspot.de/2013/01/how-to-use-google-maps-in-your-own.html?m=1. Где-то еще видел реализацию Яндекс-карт. Суть решения сводится к замене TileSource у стандартного контрола карт

UPD Вот, яндекс-карты - http://i-liger.com/article/custom-map-application-windows-phone-7